# How to add checked button in android-uitableview

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I try to implement checked button in [android-uitableview](https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/android-uitableview)

But i cannot handle the click in the checkedbutton and UItableView.

How can i resolve this problem?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i must add several clickable areas : http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=525

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener(){

      public void onClick(View v){

      mButton1.setChecked(true);

      }

 }
```

**EDITED:**

Provide your `Checkboxes with Ids`...and then **setOnClickListener on them**..

Comment: when i click button, UItable also handle the click